# Getting Wordpress Data from Custom Table does not work when WHERE is added

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have tried everything I can find on selecting wordpress mysql data from a custom table. I am able to access the table and do a var_dump(). So I know I am getting the right table.

The issue comes in when I add any WHERE or SELECT values. When I do so I end up getting an array with no values returned.

Here is my array that works in PHPMyAdmin...

```
SELECT `COL9` FROM `MLSAndrew2` WHERE `COL4` = 'R1088772' LIMIT 1
```

Here is my similar search in the PHP of my wordpress theme...

```
$datas= $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT 'COL9' FROM MLSAndrew WHERE 'COL4' = 'R1088772'");
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I haven't been able to find a solution anywhere else on why this could be happening.

Here is some of the data direct from the var_dump of the full table...

object(stdClass)#1145 (12) { ["COL1"]=> string(3) "115" ["COL2"]=> string(20) "PearlTOMeigsTOMonroe" ["COL3"]=> string(6) "750.00" ["COL4"]=> string(7) "R290029" ["COL5"]=> string(0) "" ["COL6"]=> string(6) "Monroe" ["COL7"]=> string(3) "431" ["COL8"]=> string(19) "Joseph M. Cattalani" ["COL9"]=> string(19) "joe@CBRochester.com" ["COL10"]=> string(12) "585-329-4601" ["COL11"]=> string(29) "Park Avenue Land Company LTD." ["COL12"]=> string(12) "585-271-8000" } [5]=>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your quotes. Try to change to this:

```
$datas= $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT COL9 FROM MLSAndrew WHERE COL4 = 'R1088772'");
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you. The documentation I was seeing was showing nothing but with ''. I get the following output.... array(1) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1084 (1) {
    ["COL9"]=>
    string(19) "cassremax@gmail.com"
  }
}        Any idea I can access only the string within. cassremax@gmail.com?

Comment: Glad to be able to help. 'COL4' = 'R1088772' is comparing two strings so that's never going to be true and that's why you were getting no results.

Comment: Sorry. Not familiar with PHP.